# execute python script everytime the API gets request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

This is my simple rest api

I'm getting the `jira` variable from the `get_jira` script

This is another python script which sends POST request to jira rest api to get a new jira ID

And it works fine but only once. When I start my application and send GET request to it, it gives me new jira ID, let's say `ABC-01`. The problem is when I send another GET request to get next jira ID, it gives me `ABC-01` again

Looks like the `get_jira` is executed only once, no matter how many GET request I'll send. The only way is to restart the app

Is there any way to get new jira ID (`jira`) everytime I send GET request to my api?

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, request
import fileinput

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Get(Resource):
        def get(self):

                ### ACCEPTED PARAMETERS
                source = request.get_json(force=True)['source']
                desc = request.get_json(force=True)['desc']

                ###
                .
                .
                ###

           ---> from get_jira import jira

                return jsonify({"desc":desc},{"source": source},{"jira": jira})

api.add_resource(Get, '/api/v1.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=5000,debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imports should be done at the top of your file for several reasons that I wont get into here, but I think you would do well to do a bit of research into how imports in python work.

From what I understand of your code, it could be reformatted as follows. Note that this assumes you have a file named get_jira.py which contains a function named generate_jira that returns a new jira name each time its run.

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, request
from get_jira import generate_jira
import fileinput

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Get(Resource):
    def get(self):

            ### ACCEPTED PARAMETERS
            source = request.get_json(force=True)['source']
            desc = request.get_json(force=True)['desc']
            jira = generate_jira()

            return jsonify({"desc":desc},{"source": source},{"jira": jira})

api.add_resource(Get, '/api/v1.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```